# What is a strategy in Nest JS?

Tags: nestjs, backend

I watch a guide regarding Nest JS and when working with guards the author wrote some JWT strategies but did not really focus on what they are and what is their purpose, so my question is what is a strategy?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication
https://wanago.io/2020/05/25/api-nestjs-authenticating-users-bcrypt-passport-jwt-cookies/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure he was using passport library for authentication.
Passport is middleware for Node.js that makes it easy to implement authentication and authorization.

#### Strategy design pattern

It is a behavioral software design pattern that enables selecting an algorithm at runtime.
[More about it](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)

#### Passport Strategy

It is a way to define custom algorithm/logic to authenticate users.
Passport has a lot of strategies like JWT, facebook, google and more..
You extend a strategy and add your custom logic like from where to get the user, how to validate the user and options passed to passport.

Here's a full guide:
https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication